# How to delete conntrack in kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, netfilter

I found the following code that delete netfilter conntrack in the kernel

```
int delete_nat_entry(u32 loc_ip, u32 rem_ip, u16 loc_port, u16 rem_port) {
        struct nf_conntrack_tuple_hash *h;
        struct nf_conntrack_tuple tuple;
        struct nf_conn *ct;

        memset(&tuple, 0, sizeof(tuple));

        //layer 3
        tuple.src.l3num = PF_INET;
        tuple.src.u3.ip = htonl(loc_ip);
        tuple.dst.u3.ip = htonl(rem_ip);

        //layer 4
        tuple.dst.protonum = IPPROTO_TCP;
        tuple.dst.dir = IP_CT_DIR_ORIGINAL;
        tuple.src.u.tcp.port = htons(loc_port);
        tuple.dst.u.tcp.port = htons(rem_port);

        h = nf_conntrack_find_get(&init_net, NF_CT_DEFAULT_ZONE, &tuple);
        if (!h) {
                debug_msg(KERN_INFO "cannot find conntrack tuple\n");
                return -ENOENT;
        }
        ct = nf_ct_tuplehash_to_ctrack(h);

        if (del_timer(&ct->timeout))
                nf_ct_delete(ct, 0, 0);

        nf_ct_put(ct);

        return 0;
}
```

But I do not know how to integrate in the kernel ?
and how to call it from user space?

Comment: Are you sure you want to integrate anything into kernel? What's wrong with using the `conntrack-tools` to delete/manage whatever (http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html)?

Comment: I have to cross build conntrack and dependencies. It takes spaces in my device. And I want only to remove some conntrack that's all

Comment: If I remember correctly, conntrack is controlled via a netlink socket. So technically you can write a really small C program using the appropriate netlink messages to do exactly what you need (taking conntrack-tools as reference). You can, of course, patch the kernel if you feel like it - there are quite a few tutorials around on writing Linux driver which will be helpful to get the idea about the kernel compilation process.